# Parallax Effect on Mobile Device/iPad?

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile, parallax

I have a parallax effect using just HTML/CSS on my site, it is working in all browsers, with the exception of IE7/8 I just have a normal image displayed instead, this way the user is not seeing a horrible white gap.  Just wondered if there is a workaround for viewing parallax effect on mobile devices/iPads etc? Or a way I can just set a default image, like I have done for IE7+8

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/6pgb8/9/) of the parallax effect I have.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <div id="ie7_christmas_parallax">
        <img src="xmas/ie7_ie8.jpg">
    </div>
    <![endif]-->   <!--[if IE 8]>
    <div id="ie7_christmas_parallax">
        <img src="xmas/ie7_ie8.jpg">
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
<h1>My Page</h1>
<h2>Flowers, Flowers, Flowers </h2>
```

```
    <div id="slide2" class="slide" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-slide="2"> </div>

<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>
<h2>Some text goes here</h2>

#slide4 {background-image: url("http://ibmsmartercommerce.sourceforge.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Roses_Bunch_Of_Flowers.jpeg");
-webkit-background-size: contain;
float: left;
margin-top:20px;
height: 450px;}

.slide {background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for change the css depending on width of screen
Normally the width of mobiles is from 320 to 768, so :

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 // your css code here
}
```